# How to select Java graphics with radio buttons

Tags: java, swing

Hi so I am trying to get a java image to display when you choose a radio button, so I'm using this code with an if statement to discern the button input. but I cant get the image to appear.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
    
public class Button1 extends JPanel {          
    static String sadString = "Sad Joffrey";
    static String happyString = "Happy Joffrey";
    public Button1() {                
    JRadioButton sadButton = new JRadioButton(sadString);
    sadButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    sadButton.setActionCommand(sadString);
    sadButton.setSelected(true);
        
    JRadioButton happyButton = new JRadioButton(happyString);
    happyButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    happyButton.setActionCommand(happyString);
        
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(sadButton);
    group.add(happyButton);
    JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    radioPanel.add(sadButton);
    radioPanel.add(happyButton);
    class Draw extends JComponent {
         public void paint(Graphics g) {
             if (happyButton.isSelected()) {
                 g.setColor(Color.black);
                 g.drawRect (10, 10, 200, 200);
                 g.fillOval (25, 35, 50, 50);
                 g.fillOval (150, 35, 50, 50);        
                 g.fillArc(75, 100, 100, 75, -200, 200);

             }        
        } 
    }
    add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30,30,300,300));
}
public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button1");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    JComponent newContentPane = new Button1();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.getContentPane().add(new Draw());
}       
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
    createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

I didn't put the sad face drawing in yet but above I would like to display the code in the if statement if that button is pressed, else, it would disply the sad one, So how would I draw the right code?

Comment: You're creating two JFrames, one called `frame` that displays and holds the Button1 object, the other called `window` that is never displayed. Is this what you really want to do? Before moving forward, you will want to fully clarify exactly what it is that you are trying to do, both for yourself and for us.

Comment: why are you not working with `actionlistener` ?

Comment: `ActionListener sliceActionListener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        AbstractButton aButton = (AbstractButton) actionEvent.getSource();
        if(aButton.getText()=="happyButton") //some code here
      }
    };`

Comment: Your code does not compile. You need to get all your data in order so everybody (i.e. the components it concerns) can access the requiered data. First of all the `Draw` class is defined _within_ the `Button1` constructor, and thus cannot be used outside of that. And even if you move `Draw` to class or file level, you try to use the `happyButton` variable which once again is local variable to the constructor. Having said that, @Mohsen_Fatemi is right, try using an `ActionListener` to handle input events.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) as an [edit] to the question. 2) The typical way to approach this is to add listeners to the button(s) then call `repaint()` when there is an action.

Comment: I'm trying to display a Java image with the selection of a button

Comment: *"I'm trying to.."* Who are you replying to? Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, I couldn't follow your code so as a challenge to myself I started from scratch.  Here is what I came up with...

```
public class Button1 extends JPanel { 

    boolean sad=false;
    boolean happy=false;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        if (sad) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
        }

        if (happy) {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect (10, 10, 200, 200);
            g.fillOval (25, 35, 50, 50);
            g.fillOval (150, 35, 50, 50);        
            g.fillArc(75, 100, 100, 75, -200, 200);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Button1 panel=new Button1();
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.addButtons(frame);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addButtons(JFrame frame) {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        JRadioButton sadButton = new JRadioButton("Sad");
        sadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                happy=false;
                sad=true;
                repaint();
            }
        });


        JRadioButton happyButton = new JRadioButton("Happy");
        happyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sad=false;
                happy=true;
                repaint();
            }
        });

        buttonPanel.add(sadButton);
        buttonPanel.add(happyButton);
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(sadButton);
        group.add(happyButton);
        frame.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't compile for me,

Comment: It should.  worked for me just now.  What's the error it's giving.  Make sure you add your package at the top.